# Pairs function doesn't work in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to plot Banknote data frame from alr3 package.My pairs function throws me error and doesn't give me correct plot when I execute it.Can someone tell me what's going wrong here? Thanks.

Basically I am trying to write code to find out all the counterfeit banknotess from "banknote" data frame present in "alr3" package.

**Code:-**

```
pairs(banknote[,-1],panel=
function(x,y,fake){
xy <- cbind(x,y)
points(xy[fake==0,],pch=15)
points(xy[fake==1,],pch=0)
}, fake=Y)
```

**Errors:-**

```
Error in points(xy[fake == 0, ], pch = 15) : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In plot.window(...) : "fake" is not a graphical parameter
2: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "fake" is not a graphical parameter
3: In title(...) : "fake" is not a graphical parameter
4: In plot.window(...) : "fake" is not a graphical parameter
5: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "fake" is not a graphical parameter
6: In title(...) : "fake" is not a graphical parameter
7: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "fake" is not a graphical parameter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echoing @DWin, it is not clear what `Y` is, given that it will try and get `Y` from your workspace.

If you mean to set the `pch` by the column `Y` within `banknote`, then the following will work

```
pairs(banknote[,-c(1,7)], 
  panel = function(x,y,...){
    points(x,y,pch = ifelse(as.logical(banknote$Y), 0,15))})
```

[image]

If you don't want to have to reference the `data.frame` and column using `$` then you could wrap everything within a `with(banknote, ...)` statement, then `R` will look within `banknote` to find the variables first

So the following will work

```
with(banknote, pairs(list(Left = Left, Right = Right, Bottom = Bottom, 
        Top = Top, Diagonal = Diagonal), 
      panel = function(x,y) points(x,y, pch= ifelse(as.logical(Y),0,15)))
```

Comment: Y is a class attribute coming from banknote data frame.

Comment: `attribute` has a specific meaning in `R`, as does `class` - as your statement stands, it could mean anything. If you mean that `Y` is a `column` in the `data.frame` `banknote`, then say that! - and my answer deals with this case.

Answer (score 2):

The error: Apparently `length(fake) > nrow(xy)` at the time the evaluation is being done.

The warning: Your 'fake=Y' argument is outside the curly braces, so it is being interpreted as an argument passed to pairs. I cannot tell what you are expecting it to do, and you have not shown the data that might exist in your workspace, so  ... ???

Comment: Without dput() done on your modified dataframe that could mean almost anything except what you said. It's almost certainly not an `attribute`.